# Postgres issue with Gount / Group By / date_trunc()

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I know that there are a couple of threads regarding this, but I read them all w/o any luck.

I have the following query :

```
select coalesce(count(*)), date_trunc('month', generate_series(min(item.updated_at), max(item.updated_at), '1 month'))
            from item 
            group by date_trunc('month', item.updated_at) 
            order by date_trunc ;
```

but it only shows months where items where updated at. And it just skips months with 0 matches.

I tried adding coalesce and generating the series with generate_series(), but it's still not working.

Any clues?.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You will need to calculate starting_month and ending month, then use generate_series to fill the gap, and, finally, `LEFT JOIN` the result to your `item` table.

Comment: I'm doing that by sending min() and max() as parameters

Comment: You meed a separate (sub-)query to generate these values.